# Compare two cell array elements in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I am trying to compare two cell arrays, 1x160 (a) and 80x1(b). My cell arrays consist of cells which have a number of strings inside. I wanna compare each string ans see if they are equal, then if they are equal, insert to new array, or insert 0 otherwise. I can't find any function for that. I tried 'isequal','strfind' and others. All of them give me next error message:

> If any of the input arguments are cell arrays, the first must be a
>   cell array of strings and the second must be a character array.

Here is my code!

```
function [inter]=Intersect2(a,b)
int=cell(0);
b2=[b;b];

for i=1:length(a)   
    if a{i,1}==b2{i,1}(1) ( or 'isequal','strfind')
       int{i}=a{i};
    else
        int{i}=0;
    end     
end
```

Comment: To clarify, you are not trying to find the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of the two cell arrays, but are instead matching across common indices. Correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to compare character arrays, one of which is [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html).

We'll use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) as well to avoid looping.

```
a = {'Dude', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'moose'};
b = {'Well', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'mouse'};

index = cellfun(@strcmp, a, b);
```

This will compare each element of `a` against the corresponding element in `b`, returning a logical array `index` that is `1` when the elements match and `0` when they do not.

Use this to assign matching values:

```
int = cell(1, length(a));
int(index) = a(index);
```

> int =
>
> []    'I'    'am'    'a'    []

You can extend this concept to find the set intersection if you wish.

Comment: Excellent choice of strings.

Comment: That's a good way, but what can I do if my arrays are different size?

Comment: It depends. If you're matching index-to-index, you'll have to truncate one or pad the other - the extra data is meaningless anyway. If you want to match some other way, like an intersection, you can likely use `strcmp` but you'll certainly need new code.

Comment: The extra data may not be meaningless if the if the order matters, eg {'a','b','c','d'} and {'c','a','d'}. Are there anyway to compare cells of different length?